# Override a:hover style to be the same as normal style?

Tags: html, css

I have a link with:

- a - background-color: red;
- a:hover - background-color: green;

I'm now creating a new global class 'disabled' to apply here and in other links (with other background colors) that does this:

- a.disabled - opacity: 0.7; (so in the initial example it shows background red with opacity 0.7)
- a.disabled:hover - same as a.disabled; (initial example should show background *red* with opacity 0.7)

Basically the disabled class also disables the 'hover' effect of changing the background color.

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out a solution for this that works as a global class (obviously if I set a.disabled:hover background-color: red it works).

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: green;
}

.disabled {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.disabled:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
  background-color: initial;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">click me</a>
<a href="#" class="disabled">disabled me</a>
```

Main problem is here:

```
.disabled:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
  background-color: initial;
}
```

As I can't figure out a value to put on the background-color that basically just 'nulls' the background-color: green instruction.

Again: I know setting it to 'red' works. But I have other links with blue and yellow background-colors and in that case it won't work.

Is there any clever, global way to achieve this or I just have to create different .disabled classes for my 'blue, red and yellow' links?

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to this:

```
a.disabled{
  pointer-events:none;
}
```

Actually it does more than just preserving its background, It disables click events too

**Edit:**

Just to prevent hover your `a:hover` should be altered to this:

```
a:not(.disabled):hover
```

And remove the `.disabled:hover`

(OR)

Seems you have to change the structure if you want the CSS to be common:
No other way i can think of:

```css
.linkBlue:hover{
  background-color:blue;
  }

.linkRed:hover{
  background-color:red;
  }

.linkYellow:hover{
  background-color:yellow;
  }

.linkGreen:hover{
  background-color:green;
  }

.disabled{
  cursor:not-allowed;
  }

.disabled a
{
  pointer-events:none;
}
```

```html
<a class="linkBlue">Link1</a>
<span class='disabled'><a class="linkRed">Link1</a></span>
<a class="linkYellow">Link1</a>
<span class='disabled'><a class="linkGreen">Link1</a></span>
```

Comment: That's very clever! Never thought of using that. I'll wait for more answers because this has problem of disabling pointer-events all together which means if you try something like cursor: not-allowed on the .disabled class it won't work.

Comment: Using a:not(.disabled):hover requires me to do the thing I'm trying to avoid: a:not(.disabled):hover, a--myBlueLink:not(.disabled):hover and a--myYellowLink:not(.disabled):hover. It works but gives me the same trouble of just creating 3 different disabled classes for my blue, red and yellow links. 

I take it from your edit that there isn't any way to 'nullify' the background-color: green instruction and we have to work 'around' it?

Comment: Do all the links have same background color without hover?

Comment: no. that's the difference between them. I have links where background-color is red, blue or yellow. Also different hover background-colors between those. When disabled they should show their default color with opacity 0.7 and basically don't present the 'hover' effect of changing background-color.  Also on disabled I have a cursor: not-allowed but I didn't mention that on my initial question so I won't invalidate accepting a right answer because of that.

Comment: You might have to change the structure then if you want css to be common. I have added a snipet

Answer (score 1):

According the the CSS specification initial value is :

> Each property has an initial value, defined in the property’s
>   definition table. If the property is not an inherited property, and
>   the cascade does not result in a value, then the specified value of
>   the property is its initial value.

The initial value for the background-color property is transparent. This is the reason why

```
.disabled:hover {
  background-color: initial;
}
```

differ from your expected output.

But you can do it in other way. Could you try this CSS. Hope it will help.

```
a:not(.disabled):hover {
    background-color: green;
}

.disabled:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
}
```